# Can't type in guest session terminal windows

Tags: command-line, lightdm

A little background, I have updated my machine to ubuntu 18.04 from scratch.  Then I installed lightdm in order to bring back the temp guest session from Ubuntu v16.  I liked having it for the kids.  I am fully aware of the security implications of bringing it back, that isn't my issue. What I am having an issue with is that when a terminal is opened, you can't type in it.  I am not sure if it is the shell or lack there of that the guest account is set up with, or if there is a setting to disable the use of a terminal.  It works fine from my normal user account, it is just the temporary lightdm guest session that is the issue.  I can see the cursor, and it doesn't move when you type.  I am aware of color changes and have tried playing with that to verify that it isn't a color change, the cursor doesn't move, so it is as if the input is being blocked.  I can't paste text into it either.  I have even typed known commands ls, etc. to verify that it wasn't just a visibility thing and that it actually isn't being taken.  Do any of you know of a setting or where the shell needs to be set to make the terminal work properly? Thanks in advance, CB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an administrator type the following in the terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session
```

Add the following line

```
# Allow gnome-terminal
unix (send, receive, accept) type=stream addr="@/tmp/dbus*",
```

It should look like this:

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
# Profile for restricting lightdm guest session

#include <tunables/global>

/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session {
  # Most applications are confined via the main abstraction
  #include <abstractions/lightdm>

  # chromium-browser needs special confinement due to its sandboxing
  #include <abstractions/lightdm_chromium-browser>

  # fcitx and friends needs special treatment due to C/S design
  /usr/bin/fcitx ix,
  /tmp/fcitx-socket-* rwl,
  /dev/shm/* rwl,
  /usr/bin/fcitx-qimpanel ix,
  /usr/bin/sogou-qimpanel-watchdog ix,
  /usr/bin/sogou-sys-notify ix,
  /tmp/sogou-qimpanel:* rwl,

  # Allow ibus
  unix (bind, listen) type=stream addr="@tmp/ibus/*",

  # mozc_server needs special treatment due to C/S design
  unix (bind, listen) type=stream addr="@tmp/.mozc.*",

  # Allow gnome-terminal
  unix (send, receive, accept) type=stream addr="@/tmp/dbus*",

}
```

Save the file, try restarting apparmor

```
sudo systemctl restart apparmor
```

If you don't get anything when restarting the service, the profile is ok, else if you get an error, try to correct the syntax of the file, theres probably a mistake made.
Now login as the guest account and the terminal should be working.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it didn't seem to resolve the issue though.  It is as if the gnome-terminal is stuck in read-only mode even though the check-mark is off.  However it only happens under the dynamically created guest session.  Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited my post, you should check these steps. We had the same issue with new installs of 18.04 (no upgrade) and this resolved the problem. If it doesn't can you please send the apparmor errors from /var/log/kern.log when you open the gnome-terminal / gnome-shell in the guest account so I can analyze these errors.

Comment: Awsome, thanks, I can't believe I didn't think to restart the service. Silly on my part.  Thank you for your time.